# Angular settings for DigitalOcean deploy

Tags: angular, configuration, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy angular app on DigitalOcean. I created application from App menu there and it says that it got built successfuly. But when I visit my live url, it says Cannot get / (404 from console)

[image: Main view]

However when I access my REST endpoint (API), then it prints result nicely:

[image: api view]

This in my opinion indicates that the problem seems to be maybe in routing? If so, then what changes I might need to do in order to make it work (I would also like to add that locally everything works as expected).

Comment: as per response some error has occurred while building and can you also check console there you also might get some idea what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

LOL! The issue simply was about Angular dist folder. ng build put my stuff into dist/*Project Name*, but eventually I simply changed "outputPath" (in angular.json) from "outputPath" : "dist/*Project Name*" to "outputPath" : "dist/" and it started working then.